# Java Eclipse LocalDate cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: java

I am working with Java and trying to write a very simple test code like this to test LocalDate

```
package com.journaldev.java8.time;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class calendartest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Current Date
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println("Current Date=" + today);
    }
}
```

I am sure that my java version is 8 because I checked by cmd and here is the result
[image]

But unfortunately, when I ran my code, the result is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    LocalDate cannot be resolved to a type
    LocalDate cannot be resolved
```

Could you please give me some comments ? Thank you very much!

Comment: How are you trying to compile the code? In an IDE or via cmd?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I used Eclipse to compile my code and got this error. Could you please give me some ideas ?

Comment: Post a screenshot of your Eclipse window, showing both the code and the compilation error

Answer (score 1):

I can't see that on the image you uploaded, but be sure that source code file goes under src/default package. It should not be in the project's root directory.

To change the Java Version of project you can follow instructions given on this link : https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-change-java-version.

By the way, I see that you checked **"Use default compilance setting"** checkbox, that is why your change is not applied. Uncheck that option and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your comments. Here is my answer for my problem after 4 hours, finally I found that, I used Eclipse Helios 2010, so that I can not upgrade from Jdk 1.7 to Jdk 1.8. When I changed FROM Eclipse Helios to Eclipse Luna, ALL my problems have been gone. By the way thanks for your comments and wish you all the best.